# jQuery datatable with footer, column reordering doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

here is the html code for my datatable:

```
<table id="table" width="100%">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="header0">number</th>
                <th id="header1">name</th>                  
                <th id="header2">project</th>
                <th id="header3">date</th>
                <th id="header4">status</th>                    
                <th id="header5">total</th>          
            </tr>
            <tfoot >
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">total:</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>        
        </thead>            
   </table>
```

I have `colReorder` set to true for this table. As long as I remove the footer of the table, the column ordering seems to be working fine. But when I have the footer and try to drag and drop the columns, it is only the column headings that are moving, leaving the data as it is and resulting in the following error in the console : `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`Is there any other way to solve this issue or at least a way to show the total without using the `footer`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [the issue involves the colspan in the footer](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17927/uncaught-domexception-with-colreorder-and-footer-row-with-colspan). That discussion dates back to 2013, so I don't think there's a solution for this except trying to show the total without the colspan (maybe duplicate the headers in the footer and apply `invisiblity: hidden` to the irrelevant ones?).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sebastian. I think I would rather prefer disabling the colReorder. The issue for doing this is, I am using the same method to crate a bunch of datatables in my application. If I need to set colReorder to false, I need to write a new method just for this table. Is there a way to dynamically disable colReordering after table initialization?

Comment: I don't really know how you're handling your tables initialization, but I imagine you could have a global var `colReorder`, initially true, that you could use in the table init, and also include the `destroy:true` in the init options. If you need to initialize this table, you could set the global var to false and reinitialize the datatable as if it was the first time (`destroy:true` would allow this). Hope it helps!